# Entity Framework Core raw SQL issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a `History` table with columns `C0, C1, C2, C3, TimeStamp`.

I want to select a specific column based on input along with corresponding `TimeStamp`.

Let `channelId` be 'C2'

```
var context = new DalModels.DbContext();
string command = "SELECT TimeStamp, @channelId FROM dbo.History";
var user = new SqlParameter("@channelId", channelId);
var result = context.History.FromSql(command, user).ToList();
```

But instead of a result, I get an exception:

> No column name was specified for column 2 of 'h'.
>
> Invalid column name 'C0'.
>
> Invalid column name 'C1'.
>
> Invalid column name 'C2'.
>
> Invalid column name 'C3'.
>
> Invalid column name 'TimeStamp'.

Comment: what is channelId?

Comment: You need : string channelId = "C2";

Comment: @SpiritBob channelID is a column name which can vary

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parameterized query cannot be used for the dynamic column name. Parameters are to be used only on the right-hand-side of expression, e.g. after an `=`.

To solve your problem, convert the query to use a variable.

```
var context = new DalModels.DbContext();
string command = $"SELECT TimeStamp, {channelId} FROM dbo.History";
var result = context.History.FromSql(command, user).ToList();
```

Note that `$` is used for [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

You will then have to whitelist the values that users can pass to the field to prevent SQL injection attacks.

Comment: True, but that's just the (SQL) half of the story. `FromSql` requires selecting *all* the entity columns, so cannot be used in such scenario anyway.

Comment: @IvanStoev is correct, there is a [limitation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql#limitations) in `FromSql`. In this case, the approach would be then to fetch all the columns using `context.History.ToList();` & then do some manipulation in the code.